# Why can't ESLint check syntax against Node.js version?

Tags: eslint

I'm developing in a Node-only environment. In my `.eslintrc` file:

```json
"env": {
  "node": true
}
```

I have a Node version specified in my `package.json` file:

```json
"engines": {
  "node": ">=16.13.0"
}
```

The first `const` encountered causes the `Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved` error to be thrown. I know that I can get rid of it by specifying the `ecmaVersion` to ESLint. But why can't ESLint figure out by itself what Node version is in use, and make [the appropriate keywords and global variables](https://node.green/) (e.g. Promises) available to us without redundant code?

Plus, from what I understand **ECMA specification ≠ Node**. So by specifying an ECMA version, we might actually make ESLint believe a feature is available whereas it's not, don't we?

Comment: If you needed to support specific browsers, or maybe older runtime versions of Node while still developing in a new installation, this would not be a smart solution. But you could create a plugin for this.

Comment: I assume here that I'm developing for a node-only environment. And I'm not interested in supporting any older versions of Node.js, as my code would break running on such versions (that's why I set `package.engines.node` in the first place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`eslint-plugin-node`](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node) package is doing exactly that.

It internally maintains a [map of ECMAScript features and the minimal version of Node that support them](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node/blob/v11.1.0/lib/rules/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax.js), that's based on [node.green](https://node.green).

It reads the engines field of `package.json` to detect which Node.js versions our module is supporting.

Its `node/no-unsupported-features` rule reports unsupported ECMAScript syntax on the configured Node.js version as lint errors.

Only problem is that it supports up to ECMAScript 2019 only and hasn't been touched for two years.

So the answer to the question is: **it can**, though you'll have to build your own plugin to achieve that since there's no up-to-date solution as of today.

Comment: There is a fork of that plugin, which seems to be maintained: https://github.com/eslint-community/eslint-plugin-n

Answer (score -1):

When [configuring ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/), and in particular [specifying environments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments):

> An environment provides predefined global variables.

Thus, configuring `env` does not indicate which ECMAScript syntax (language features) you'd like to use, but rather which predefined globals are in play.

Moreover, under the [parser options](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-parser-options), you can see that:

> By default, ESLint expects ECMAScript 5 syntax.

Thus, you need to explicitly opt-in to which ES6+ features of ECMAScript you'd like to support because ESLint will not infer the language options you want to use by reading the `engine` field of your package.json file when using `env: { node: true }`.

You can get support for `const` and other ES6 features by including the relevant `parserOptions`, as you noted:

```js
parserOptions: {
  ecmaVersion: 6 // Or whatever version you want to target
}
```

Interestingly, you can also get support for `const` (and other ES6 features) by including the `es6` environment:

```js
env: {
  node: true, // To keep support for Node globals
  es6: true
}
```

This works becuase

> this automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 6